# getting template resolver issue on aws working perfectly fine on local host

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

```
Jul 11 21:09:09 ip-172-31-10-183 web: 2021-07-11 21:09:09.153 ERROR 1871 --- [nio-5000-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [index], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers] with root cause
Jul 11 21:09:09 ip-172-31-10-183 web: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [index], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
Jul 11 21:09:09 ip-172-31-10-183 web: at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:869) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.12.RELEASE]
Jul 11 21:09:09 ip-172-31-10-183 web: at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.12.RELEASE]
Jul 11 21:09:09 ip-172-31-10-183 web: at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.12.RELEASE]
Jul 11 21:09:09 ip-172-31-10-183 web: at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.12.RELEASE]
Ju
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this exact issue today, everything worked fine locally but the second I uploaded my app to AWS I got this same error.

This was my controller

```java
public class SiteController {

    @GetMapping({"/","","index"})
    public RedirectView index(){
        return new RedirectView("/coming-soon");
    }

    @GetMapping("coming-soon")
    public String comingSoonForm(){
        return "/coming-soon";
    }
    ...
```

Then in my resources directory I had the following

```
resources
│
└───templates
    │   coming-soon.html
    │   index.html
    │
    └───fragments
            elements.html
```

As I knew there was nothing wrong with my directory naming, I tried the first thing that came to mind, and **removed the leading slashes** from my method return values.
For example instead of my comingSoonForm() method returning `/coming-soon`, I made it return `coming-soon` then pushed back to AWS and [problem solved]